# Create Flux with ability to publish arbitrary events in future

Tags: java, spring-webflux, reactive-programming

I'd like to create a custom `Flux` with the ability to publish arbitrary events in future.

Eg:

```java
@RestController
public class EventController {
    @GetMapping(path = "/event/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> eventStream() {
       // how to create a flux here which I can publish arbitrary events to in future?
    }
}
```

I've seen the `Flux.from(...)` and `Flux.generate(...)` methods in the [Flux javadocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html) but these don't seem to do what I need

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this with [Sinks.many()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.html#many--)

```java
Many<String> emitter = Sinks.many().unicast().onBackpressureBuffer();
Flux<String> flux = emitter.asFlux();
```

I can now

- publish future events via [emitter.emitNext(...)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.Many.html#emitNext-T-reactor.core.publisher.Sinks.EmitFailureHandler-)
- complete the stream via [emitter.emitComplete(...)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Sinks.Many.html#emitComplete-reactor.core.publisher.Sinks.EmitFailureHandler-)